# .click() function stops working after form submit on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which has a form with 10 fields including select boxes, radio fields and text boxes. It takes the parameters, queries the database and prints the results on the same page. 
I am also using $_POST[''] on the same page to hold on to the form values and not lose it.

I have many methods which use the .click function in this page. They all work fine before the first submit. After the first submit with all the parameters, the .click function stops working. None of the jquery code with .click function work.

Does this have anything to do with the server returning information on the same page or with the way im holding on to the form information using $_POST[''] ?

Here is a piece of code that uses .click function.

```
    <!-- Clear form data after form submission -->
<script language="Javascript">
function resetForm($form) {
    alert("resetting form");
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
    .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}
</script>

<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clear_form").click(function(){
    alert("clear form button clicked");
    resetForm($('#search_query'));
    });
});
</script>
```

The form is submitted in the following manner.

```
<form method="POST" action="samepage.php" name="form1" id="formid" onsubmit="return validate_Form()">
# Bunch of text fields, select boxes, radio buttons,

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

At the very beginning of the page I collect the form data to automatically fill in the form fields after the submit to retain the form data.

```
$x = $_POST['x'];
```

And if the form submit is succesfull (.ie passing all the form validation ) i collect the data again to query the database and print the results on the same page.

```
$xx = $_POST['x]
```

I have a custom validation funciton that i wrote which basically just checks if the fields are empty or not, nothing fancy. Its setup in such a way that atleast one field must be entered in order for the form to be submitted to the server.

Comment: W/o seeing much of your code one suggestion is to check out `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: The `language` attribute is deprecated. Remove it and replace it with `type="text/javascript"` (optional, it's the default anyway). In case you are using a reasonably modern jQuery version, also replace those removeAttr calls with `.prop('checked', false).prop('selected', false)`

Comment: Are you using AJAX? Are you using "input type='submit'" ?

Comment: you might ant to view source on the page anc check for JS errors on your javascript console. its possible `PHP` is outputting error messages that *break* the dom interaction with jquery.

Comment: Im not using AJAX. Its php/html. The input type is submit. Im afraid i wont be able to post the entire code here. Any particular part of the code that you are interested in ?

Comment: It's difficult to determinate the problem with just that code you posted. I would be usefull to see how you post the form and how you handle the server response.

Comment: Ive added a little bit of more code to this, I hope this helps.

Comment: Once you submit a form, all code execution on the client stops until a new page is served.

Comment: I submit the form and i get the results on the page. That technically means a new page was served and the results are showing on the page. But that should not stop the .click function to execute after the page was served right ?

Answer (score 1):

After researching more on this problem, i finally found a solution.

```
$('#buttonid').live('click', function () {

#Your code here 

});
```

I still need to understand why this is happening. I'll re edit the answer when I find the root cause to the problem.